# Can not load Chrome default profile

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def main():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/octavian/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default");
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
    time.sleep(1000)


main()
```

I am trying to load my Facebook profile. However, the page that is opened doesn't have my profile(I'm not logged in), which means the browser state is not loaded.

However, my Chrome profile is stored in this file:

```
/Users/octavian/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

Why is the profile not seen by Selenium?